# Browsing PDF in a web page without using Flash

Tags: javascript, pdf, jquery-plugins

I Have an N-Pages PDF linked in a my web page.

I want to be able to browse the PDF, with next and prev arrows, page numbers, etc etc

I want to be able to browse the PDF without using any Flash Plugin.

I also want to normalize the browsing behaviour, so i don't want to use the default PDF plugin of the browser.

I'm looking for a JS plugin but i don't find interesting solutions.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

See my code below:

```
 $("a[href*=.pdf]").click(function(){
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Alternatively, you can apply the target="_self" attribute instead:

```
 $("a[href*=.pdf]").click(function(){
    $(this).attr({"target":"_self"});
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you need a plugin here it is https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js

Demo for the plugin http://deanhume.com/content/postimages/pdfjs/pdfjs.htm#1

Comment: Ok, but it seems that this solution use the plugin of the browser. Not?

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice "_so i don't want to use the default PDF plugin of the browser_" . :-)

Comment: Very good for the HTML5 solution. Bad for the retrocompatibility. DAMN IE7 and IE8. Thanks.