# View PDF in a web page without Flash

Tags: javascript

I am working on a website that need to embed weekly PDF file on a page.
We don't want to use Flash since website need to support cross browsers(like Android).
I have reviewed following topic but it doesn't meet my target since some browsers don't  support HTML5.
[Browsing PDF in a web page without using Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380963/browsing-pdf-in-a-web-page-without-flash)
I now have three options and wonder which is better.

1.Use Google Doc Viewer  -  the problem of google doc viewer is that PDF resolution can't be too high.
                                                                                             As result our PDF content become unclear.
2.[OpenLayers](http://www.OpenLayers.org/) - we have to convert our PDF file to image.
3.[DimViewer](http://www.dimviewer.com/) - this is not open source tool.

If anyone has similar experience  welcome to share.

Comment: Why not offer it as a download?

Comment: Executive level need to see it on a page and cross browsers. thanks anyway

Comment: Does anyone want to put some comments on our three options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google Doc Viewer before, yes it has some limitations like zoom in/out.

If you have more experience in open source then [OpenLayers](http://www.OpenLayers.org/) is a good option.

Otherwise commercial tools like [DimViewer](http://www.dimviewer.com/) may a good choice in terms of support.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look ad [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/).

The current Firefox introduces this as its native PDF viewer.

Comment: We are looking for a cross browsers solution without plugin.HTML5 is not an option for us.

Comment: @jimt This is a pure JavaScript library. No plugin required. I'm, however, unsure about the usage of HTML5 features, but maybe one can use polyfills, where needed.

Comment: Sirko:I have done some research on PDF.js,it require HTML5 http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/

Comment: @jimt Like I said - there are plenty of polyfills for HTML5 features out there.

Comment: Sirko:we will check polyfills features,thanks. I wonder any opinions or experence on our current three options.

Answer (score 0):

just put it in an iframe

http://jsfiddle.net/gAH8F/

Comment: Just try on my Android browser, it doesn't work.I guess I have to convert PDF to image which all of my three above options did.I just want to get some experience people's opinion about our options.