# PDF to JPG converter

Tags: javascript, pdf, jpeg

Is there any way to covert a PDF file into a JPG using Javascript?

I have already tried finding a converter, but all I have got till now is [a Javascript to embed a PDF file into an HTML page](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/).

Comment: do you have access to a server side language that can call ImageMagik?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert PDF to image from backend first.

Open source tools include

iText

ImageMagick

Ghostscript

then use Javascript to display image.

Following post may help

[View PDF in a web page without Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074747/view-pdf-in-a-web-page-without-flash)